# Finding and ignoring lines of text (python/tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

all. I'm trying to make a small program to launch a Minetest server and communicate with it. The problem is, I'm learning on the fly, so this is all new to me. Right now, I'm stuck on the settings portion of my window. The file I'm reading looks something like:

```
#Name of player, on a server this is the main admin
name =
#Server stuff
# Network port to listen (UDP)
port = 30000
# Bind address
bind_address =
```

And I'm trying to figure out two things.

(1) How can I get all of the lines that don't start with "#"?

(2) How can I turn each non # line into a module like a Label?

Any help with either of those would be extremely helpful. I'm not asking for code or anything, just a basic idea of what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to give specific advice without seeing your code. But take a look at the [String Methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) docs, in particular, `startswith`. You may also find `split` &/or `partition` helpful for splitting a parameter's name from its value.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Comment: "turn each ... into a module like a Label" - a Label (assuming you mean the tkinter Label class) isn't a module. Can you rephrase that? Did you mean "widget" rather than "module"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
l = []
x = file.readlines()
for line in x:
    if x[0] != '#':
        l.append(line)
```

Comment: If you encounter an empty line, `x[0]` will fail with an `IndexError`. Try replacing it with either `x and x[0] != '#'` or `'x[:1] != '#'`.